# How do I update a tableviewcell with JSON data selected from a slider in Swift 3?

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, swift3, slider

I need to update a cell with the value from a slider. The slider is pulling data from parsed JSON data.

How do I add the display the JSON data from the slider to a tableview cell?

Here is my current code:

```
import UIKit

class SliderViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var sliderTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var styleSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var abvSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var ibuSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func styleSlider(_ sender: Any) {
// LABEL CREATED FOR TESTING PURPOSES ONLY
    testLabel.text = String(Int(styleSlider.value))
}

var beersMatch = [Beer]()
var filteredBeersMatch = [Beer]()
var filters = [BeerStyle]()
var selectedCells: [Bool] = []
let apiManager = APIManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    apiManager.TapList { (fetchedBeers) in
        self.beersMatch = fetchedBeers

        var setFilters = Set<BeerStyle>()
        for beer in fetchedBeers {
            setFilters.insert(beer.StyleName)
        }

        self.filters = Array(setFilters)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.sliderTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Table view data source
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) 
-> Int {
return filteredJsonMatch.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
-> UITableViewCell {
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"SliderListCell") as? SliderTableViewCell else {
    return UITableViewCell()
}

// MARK: Beer name
let beers = filteredJsonMatch[indexPath.row]
cell.sliderMatchLabel.text = beers.BrewName
cell.sliderMatchName.text = beers.BevName
cell.sliderMatchRowNumber.text = jsons.DisplayName

if let IBU = beers.Ibu {
    cell.sliderMatchIBU.text = "\(IBU) IBU"
}

if let ABV = beers.Abv {
    cell.sliderMatchABV.text = "\(ABV)%"
}

cell.sliderMatchJsonType.text = jsons.StyleName.name
cell.sliderMatchLocation.text = jsons.Location
cell.sliderMatchKegImage.image = jsons.kegPercentageFull()

// MARK: Download image
jsons.downloadImage { (jsonImage) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.sliderMatchImage.image = jsonImage
    }
}
return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your `filteredJsonMatch`? Shouldn't it be `filters` as your added the loaded beer to your `filters` array?

In your TapList closure:

```
var setFilters = Set<BeerStyle>()
for beer in fetchedBeers {
   setFilters.insert(beer.StyleName)
}

self.filters = Array(setFilters)
```

but in when you populate the data to each cell:

```
let beers = filteredJsonMatch[indexPath.row]
```